# How can a device decipher spoken English words?

Tags: functional-programming

I want to know how it can process spoken English words and Pull out a matching response? Is it a chip or a installed software? Does it take up a lot of space? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read about [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing).  It's an entire field of research and practice.  There are many textbooks and online resources that provide an introduction to that area.